# There is a behavior of ServicePointManager in C# that I can't figure out the reason for

Tags: c#

I have a fixed line on the main interface and a mobile line connected to the sub-interface, and I want to access the same server with different interfaces at the same time.

The default routing in Windows is set for the main line, so if the interface is not specified, the communication will be on the main line.
If the `ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 0;` line is not included in the code, the first request and the second request will use the ServicePoint with the mobile line set, but if the line is included, a separate ServicePoint object will be created. The ServicePoint hash code will also be different and accessed through a different interface.
Why does setting the idle time to 0 cause the ServicePoints to be created anew?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start");
                ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 0;
                Test().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static async Task Test()
        {
            Task task = null;

            // 1st request (with interface specified)
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.cman.jp/network/support/go_access.cgi");
                req.Proxy = null;

                // Specify interface
                req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate (
                    ServicePoint servicePoint,
                    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint,
                    int retryCount)
                {
                    return new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress("192.168.42.252".Split('.').Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray()), 0);
                };

                task = new Task(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[1]Start");
                    Console.WriteLine("[1]Hash=" + req.ServicePoint.GetHashCode());

                    string htmlSource;
                    using (var webres = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                    using (var st = webres.GetResponseStream())
                    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(st, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        htmlSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("[1]" + Regex.Match(htmlSource, @"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+").Value);
                }));

                task.Start();
            }

            // By waiting a bit, the second one connects while the first one is communicating.
            await Task.Delay(50);

            // Second request (no interface specified)
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.cman.jp/network/support/go_access.cgi");
                req.Proxy = null;

                Console.WriteLine("[2]Start");
                Console.WriteLine("[2]Hash=" + req.ServicePoint.GetHashCode());

                string htmlSource;
                using (var webres = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                using (var st = webres.GetResponseStream())
                using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(st, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    htmlSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("[2]" + Regex.Match(htmlSource, @"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+").Value);
            }
            
            // Wait for the end of the first asynchronous request
            await task;
        }
    }
}
```

When I actually tested this code on a fast main line and a very slow mobile line, the IP address of the main line by the second request came up first, and then after a while, the IP address of the mobile line of the first request came up. (The URL being accessed is an IP address display site that extracts the IP address from the response and displays it.)

The output looks like this

```
Start
[1]Start
[1]Hash=11111111
[2]Start
[2]Hash=222222
[2] Main line address
[1] Mobile line address
Done
```